# Pickling custom/dynamic class definition throwing "No module named xyz" error

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pickle, python-module

I have the following function that generates/returns a custom class and that looks something like this:

Let's say this function is stored in generate_class_module.py

```py
def generate_class(custom_func):
    class MyClass:
       def __init__(self):
           self.custom_func = custom_func 
       def do_something_custom(self, arg1):
           return self.custom_func(arg1)
     return MyClass
```

And then I will try to call it another module and pickle the generated class, and the forward to some other client:

```py
import dill
from generate_class_module import generate_class

def custom_code(arg1):
    # client code/logic 
    return arg1

store_dict = {'custom_class': generate_class(custom_code)}

with open('gen_class.pkl', 'wb') as file:
     dill.dump(store_dict, file)
```

Let's say this file is sent to the other client and when they deserialze it, they get the following error: "No module named generate_class_module". I understand you have import the module in the top-level namespace, but can we do without it? I just want to store the generated custom code/class that clients can call anywhere without the need for such imports.

I tried to "mainify" where I just imported the code as a string and execute it and store it back in the `__main__` but the `custom_code` attribute/arg throws an attribute/name error when pickled.

I need it to able to somehow keep the class in the '**main**' every time I call the generate_class. Instead, the generated_class imported as "<generate_class_module.generate_class..MyClass ...>". It should look something like this "**main**.MyClass" in the store_dict.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!